# Is it possible to use VS2012 in a big project where rest of the ppl are using VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio

This might sound like a weird question but I work on a reasonably big project with a bunch of people who all commit to the same repository and we all use VS2010.
To be honest, I'm tired of it being pathetically slow ("waiting for the internal opration...") so I was thinking about buying myself VS2012.
 But the problem is that, like I said, I'm part of the big project and other people wont update to VS2012 because I don't think they care that much and don't want to give their money to upgrade their work place software. Also I don't think the company would be happy to buy new Visual Studio for various reasons. 
So is it possible for me to do development (C++, C++ CLI, C#) in VS 2012 and easily integrate with others. I wont be able to use new stuff(C++11  for example) but if I use only language stuff from VS2010 can it be done?

P.S. Please no "hire headhunter" comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Will be too hard I think. What about stuff in VS2010 that has now been deprecated in VS2012?

Edit: It takes months of planning for big teams to move onto newer versions of Visual Studio. I work on a large project and just for fun one of the guys tried compiling one of our solutions (currently VS2008) in VS2012. He faced 82k+ compilation errors (obviously fixing one would solve loads but still).

So having guys on different versions would be a nightmare I think.

Comment: idk about those things... Im only cpp dev and I dont know of any deprecated stuff regarding C++. Ofc other ppl use C# so I guess Im not upgrading. :)

Answer (score 2):

I use VS2012 RC at my work and my coworkers use VS2010 with SP1 (Mostly C# and C++).  I have to make sure to use .NET4, but as long as you stay with .NET4, I haven't ran into problems with people developing on both for the same project.  If they don't have service pack 1 for VS2010, you'll probably run into problems.  I've made projects in 2012 and opened it in 2010, and vice versa with no problems (as long as it's set to .NET4).  Also!  I have both 2010 and 2012 installed on the same machine, so that may affect some of why it works so well for me.

With version control, I noticed that VS2012 will update some of the tags in the project file to say VS2012, and then 2010 will change it to 2010, but that hasn't caused any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will gain much of a performance increase by upgrading to VS2012 over VS2010. If that is the main purpose of your upgrade I don't think it would be worth the hassle. VS2012 also cannot open a previous version without converting it to the current version so you will have continuous conflicts with your other developers. You need to weigh up the benefits of upgrading carefully before going ahead. If VS2012 has features that will definitely benefit your whole development team then maybe it can be worth it.

Comment: You can skip the update. Visual Studio 2012 RC will load and work with the project without making any changes if it has access to the Visual C++ tools in Visual Studio 2010 with SP1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690665%28v=vs.110%29.aspx